# Parsing parts of XML to different classes

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to figure out how I can read in a parts of an XML file into a class.

This is the structure of the XML File:

```
 <Root>
  <Element1>
    <Element2>
      <ElementID></ElementId>
      <Element3a>
        <Element3aId id="">0</Element3aId>
        <Element3aId id="">0</Element3aId>
      </Element3a>
      <Element3b>
        <Element3bId id="">0</Element3bId>
        <Element3bId id="">0</Element3bId>
      </Element3b>
      <Element3c>
        <Element3cId id="">0</Element3cId>
        <Element3cId id="">0</Element3cId>
      </Element3c>
    </Element2>   
  </Element1>
</Root>
```

I have created the following classes (I removed accessors/mutators to try to simplify the code:

```
public struct Element3a
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    string id;

    [XmlElement("Element3aId")]
    int Element3aId;
}

[XmlRootAttribute("Element2")]
public struct Element1
{
    [XmlElement("ElementID")]
    int id;

    List<Element3a> Element3aId;

    List<Element3a> Element3bId;

    List<Element3a> Element3cId;
}
```

Here is my parsing code:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);

var Element2List = xDoc.Root.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name.LocalName.Equals("Element1"));
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Element1));

using (var reader = Element2List.CreateReader())
{
    do
    {
        reader.ReadToDescendant("Element2");
        Element1 tag1 = (Element1)serializer.Deserialize(reader.ReadSubtree());

        // How do I populate the Element3a Lists here?

    } while (reader.ReadToNextSibling("Station"));
    reader.Close();
}
```

`Element3a`/`Element3b`/`Element3c` all have the same data in them, so I want to be able to serialize them into just the `Element3a` structs. I am able to get the `Element2` information into the `Element2` class, but I am unable to populate the `Element3a` lists in that class.

Comment: Hint: posting a valid html can help us...

Comment: How do I do that? Do you mean a html code snippet?

Comment: Ok you corrected your xml but missed one. Xml is case sensitive `ElementID!=ElementId`

Comment: Now what is the problem with `var list = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//Element2/*[starts-with(name(),'Element3')]").ToList();`

Answer (score -1):

Instead of serialize use Xml Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Element1 elements = doc.Descendants("Element2").Select(x => new Element1() {
                id = (string)x.Element("ElementID") == "" ? null : (int?)x.Element("ElementID"),
                Element3aId = x.Descendants("Element3a").Select(y => new Element3a {
                    id =  (string)y.Attribute("id"),
                    Element3aId = (string)y.Element("Element3aId") == "" ? null : (int?)y.Element("Element3aId")
                }).ToList(),
                Element3bId = x.Descendants("Element3b").Select(y => new Element3a {
                    id =  (string)y.Attribute("id"),
                    Element3aId = (string)y.Element("Element3bId") == "" ? null : (int?)y.Element("Element3bId")
                }).ToList(),
                Element3cId = x.Descendants("Element3c").Select(y => new Element3a
                {
                    id = (string)y.Attribute("id"),
                    Element3aId = (string)y.Element("Element3cId") == "" ? null : (int?)y.Element("Element3cId")
                }).ToList()
            }).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
    public struct Element3a
    {
        public string id;
        public int? Element3aId;
    }

    public struct Element1
    {
        public int? id;

        public List<Element3a> Element3aId;

        public List<Element3a> Element3bId;

        public List<Element3a> Element3cId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using this isn't getting me the Element3aId...I keep getting null there.

Comment: I got it working...didn't need the .Element("Element3aId") tag.

Comment: Did you change the xml file?  Should of worked without change.  I modified code.  The old code was always getting a instead of a,b,c.